# The method was called on null even though method was already declared

Tags: loops, flutter, dart, android-virtual-device

I was making an app and it keeps showing an error the method was called on null. When I looked up for answers it was specified that this occurs when method is not declared but in my case method has been already declared.

Due to this error I am not able to save data in my app.
initialiseDatabase is the function it states as called on null.
 Here is the code-

```
      static DatabaseHelper _databaseHelper; // singleton
      static Database _database;

      String noteTable = 'note_Table';
      String colId = 'id';
      String colTitle = 'title';
      String colDescription = 'description';
      String colPriority = 'priority';
      String colDate = 'date';

      DatabaseHelper._createInstance();// named constructor to create dbms helper

      factory DatabaseHelper(){
      if(DatabaseHelper == null) {
        _databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper._createInstance();

      }
        return _databaseHelper;
      }

            Future<Database> get database async{
              if(_database == null){
                _database = await initializeDatabase();
              }
              return _database;

            }

            Future<Database> initializeDatabase() async {
              Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
              String path = directory.path + 'notes.db';

              var notesDatabase = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDb);
              return notesDatabase;
            }

      void _createDb(Database db, int newVersion) async{
        await db.execute('CREATE TABLE $noteTable($colId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $colTitle TEXT.'
            '$colDescription TEXT, $colPriority INTEGER, $colDate TEXT');

       }


      // Fetch Operation: Get all note objects from database
      Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getNoteMapList() async {
        Database db = await this.database;

    //      var result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $noteTable order by $colPriority ASC');
        var result = await db.query(noteTable, orderBy: '$colPriority ASC');
        return result;
      }

      // Insert Operation: Insert a Note object to database
      Future<int> insertNote(Note note) async {
        Database db = await this.database;
        var result = await db.insert(noteTable, note.toMap());
        return result;
      }

      // Update Operation: Update a Note object and save it to database
      Future<int> updateNote(Note note) async {
        var db = await this.database;
        var result = await db.update(noteTable, note.toMap(), where: '$colId = ?', whereArgs: [note.id]);
        return result;
      }

      // Delete Operation: Delete a Note object from database
      Future<int> deleteNote(int id) async {
        var db = await this.database;
        int result = await db.rawDelete('DELETE FROM $noteTable WHERE $colId = $id');
        return result;
      }

      // Get number of Note objects in database
      Future<int> getCount() async {
        Database db = await this.database;
        List<Map<String, dynamic>> x = await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT (*) from $noteTable');
        int result = Sqflite.firstIntValue(x);
        return result;
      }

      // Get the 'Map List' [ List<Map> ] and convert it to 'Note List' [ List<Note> ]
      Future<List<Note>> getNoteList() async {

        var noteMapList = await getNoteMapList(); // Get 'Map List' from database
        int count = noteMapList.length;         // Count the number of map entries in db table

        List<Note> noteList = List<Note>();
        // For loop to create a 'Note List' from a 'Map List'
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          noteList.add(Note.fromMapObject(noteMapList[i]));
        }

        return noteList;
      }


    }
```

While this is the function which it states as not declared

```
  Future<Database> get database async{
      if(_database == null){
        _database = await initializeDatabase();
      }
      return _database;

    }

    Future<Database> initializeDatabase() async {
      Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      String path = directory.path + 'notes.db';

      var notesDatabase = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDb);
      return notesDatabase;
    }
```

Comment: Well, actually, you understood the error wrongly..if it states `method was called in null`..it means that you didn't call the method correctly.. for ex: it you have something like `var a = 1` and somewhere if you do `print(a.toLowerCase())` then you will get such an error as you are not supposed to called `toLowerCase()` with an `integer`..hope it brings some clarity to you.. regarding the error..now try to find where you are doing wrong..do reply if it worked for you..

Comment: @srikanth7785  actually in my program this is the only part where I use this function so any other solution or modification in this code would be of great help.